# VS Code Recreate Folding behaviour of Plain Text

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, folding

For a custom language, I what the same folding behavior of "Plain Text", meaning leaving out blank lines:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I expected Plain Text folding behavior as default, but as soon as I switch to my custom language, blank lines are included in the folding area. I set folding strategy to "indentation", with the same result.

My last attempt was setting a folding behavior in language-configuration.json:

```
    "folding": {
       "markers": {
          "start": "^\\w+",
          "end": "\\n\\n"
       }
    }
```

But no success.

How can I make this work?

VSCode 1.63.2, Windows 10 20H2

Comment: There is a setting `"offSide": true` that at least seems related. It's [used for plain text](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/ce5d3510b1488e8c763bfddbfa02c62958135495/src/vs/editor/common/languages/modesRegistry.ts#L80-L82).

Comment: Perfect, this does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Use `"offSide": true`:

```
"folding": {
   "offSide": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
In my case, this is all I need: 
    "folding": {
        "offSide": true
    }

Comment: I changed my answer to that, @Martin.